# Sending async email with Flask-Security

Tags: asynchronous, flask, flask-security, flask-mail

I'm attempting to configure Flask-Security to send email asynchronously.

I have some code which send async email via Flask-Mail, but I'm having trouble integrating it with my application factory function so that it works in conjunction with Flask-Security.

Application factory:

```
mail = Mail()
db = SQLAlchemy()
security = Security()

from app.models import User, Role
user_datastore = SQLAlchemyUserDatastore(db, User, Role)

def create_app(config_name):
    # Config
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object(config[config_name])
    config[config_name].init_app(app)

    # Initialize extensions
    mail.init_app(app)
    db.init_app(app)
    security.init_app(app, user_datastore)

    return app
```

In the Flask-Security documentation it says to use `@security.send_mail_task` to override the way the extension sends emails.

**So where exactly do I implement this decorator? Seems like anywhere I put it inside the application factory, I get circular imports.**

These are the async email functions I am trying to use, taken from [this issue](https://github.com/mattupstate/flask-security/issues/325):

```
@async
def send_security_email(msg):
    with app.app_context():
       mail.send(msg)

@security.send_mail_task
def async_security_email(msg):
    send_security_email(msg)
```

**Where does this code need to be put in order to work with the app factory?**

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to achieve this like so:

```
mail = Mail()
db = SQLAlchemy()
security = Security()

from app.models import User, Role
user_datastore = SQLAlchemyUserDatastore(db, User, Role)

def create_app(config_name):
    # Config
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object(config[config_name])
    config[config_name].init_app(app)

    # Initialize extensions
    mail.init_app(app)
    db.init_app(app)
    security_ctx = security.init_app(app, user_datastore)

    # Send Flask-Security emails asynchronously
    @security_ctx.send_mail_task
    def async_security_email(msg):
        send_security_email(app, mail, msg)

    return app
```